# Webview not playing video when the one video ended

Tags: java, android, android-studio, iframe, youtube

I am trying to play the next youtube video in android when one video ended. But webview is not playing another video.

```
        // make auto height of youtube. if you want to use 'wrap_content'
        youtubePlayerView.setAutoPlayerHeight(this);

        
        YTParams params = new YTParams();
       
        params.setVolume(100);
        params.setPlaybackQuality(PlaybackQuality.small);

        currentSec.setText(String.valueOf(0));
 YoutubePlayerView.YouTubeListener())

        
        

        youtubePlayerView.initializeWithCustomURL("p1Zt47V3pPw", params, new YoutubePlayerView.YouTubeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onReady() {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onStateChange(YoutubePlayerView.STATE state) {
                if(state.equals(YoutubePlayerView.STATE.ENDED){
                   youtubePlayerView.cueVideo("bnEZb0rB8lw");
                 }
                

               
            }
```

I want to play next video when one video ended but webview is not refreshing